# representing \xd9\x88 (UTF-8 literal) in its arabic character و in Python

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, python-3.3, arabic

I know that `\xd9\x88`is utf-8 code for the letter `و` in Arabic (you can see [this page](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1536&utf8=string-literal)).

I have a file that contains a list of such utf-8 characters, how can I represent them in Arabic characters, for example represent `\xd9\x88` with `و` ?

On Python 3 if I do:

```
>>> i = '\xd9\x88'
>>> print(i)
Ù
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "represent". Do you mean write to a file, print on the screen, etc?

Comment: For example print on Python IDLE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print the character, simply use `print()`; but you have to make sure your terminal supports the encoding and is using a font that has that glyph.

In the Windows command prompt, with the default encoding (that doesn't support Arabic), you'll see this:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> i = "\xd9\x88"
>>> print(i)
┘ê
>>>
```

On Linux, using UTF-8 as the default encoding and using a font that has the Arabic glyphs, you'll see this:

```
>>> i = "\xd9\x88"
>>> print(i)
و
>>>
```

Back on Windows, if you use a text editor that supports UTF-8 (in this case, I am using Sublime Text), you'll see:

[image: sublime-text-screencap]

> I am using IDLE for Python and Python 3 on Windows.

Python 3 introduced some major changes to how strings are handled in Python. In Python 3, all strings are stored as unicode.

You actually have a *byte string*, a string representing the code points that represent a character. So you need to decode it properly.

You can do this two ways, first is to make sure its a byte string to start with:

```
>>> i = b"\xd9\x88"
>>> print(i.decode('utf-8'))
و
```

Or, you can encode it to latin-1 first, which will give you a bytestring, then decode it:

```
>>> i = "\xd9\x88"
>>> type(i)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(i.encode('latin-1'))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> print(i.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
و
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using IDLE for Python and Python 3 on Windows.So I get this: `>>> i = "\xd9\x88"
>>> print(i)
Ù'

Comment: but on the same IDLE I can have: i = 'و'
>>> print(i)
و so the IDLE can represent Arabic words.

Comment: It is not about IDLE, its a fundamental change in Python 3 on how strings are handled. In Python 3, [all strings are unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support); which is why `"و"` works in Python 3.  Please read [this excellent article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to understand what exactly is unicode and how you should use it.